# BeautifulSoup extract json from variable as a string without TAG

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is the response i'm getting from the javascript. I'm looking for a json `string like ['stocks']['counter']`. How can I remove the variable definition var `stockData = 'string'`.

```
var stockData = {
"Stocks":
[
  {
    "counter": "ALAM",
    "open": "0.100",
    "high": "0.105",
    "low": "0.100",
    "lastdone": "0.105",
    "change": "0.005",
    "volume": "8,033",
    "percentchange": "5.00",
    "stockcode": "5115"
  }
]
};
```

Thanks
Sarwar

Comment: What about the `json` module ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot index of dictionary

```
stockData['Stocks'][0]['counter']
```